# Add a constrainst on authentication

Tags: symfony, authentication

Actually, I have a listener on `AuthenticationEvents::AUTHENTICATION_FAILURE` that stores `failedLogin` in Redis Cache, like:

```
[
  'ip' => [
    'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx' => [
      'nbAttempts' => 5,
      'lastAttempd' => \DateTime
    ],
  ],
  'username' => [
    'my_login' => [
      'nbAttempts' => 3,
      'lastAttempd' => \DateTime
    ],
    'my_other_login' => [
      'nbAttempts' => 2,
      'lastAttempd' => \DateTime
    ],
  ]
]
```

But now, I need to use this list of fails to prevent logins when a user try to connect with a username tries more than x times in n minutes, and the same for an IP (with an other ratio). (later, maybe add a ReCaptcha before block)

To do it, I need to add a custom validation rules on the login. I've found it in the documentation:

- http://symfony.com/doc/current/security/custom_password_authenticator.html
- https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/guard_authentication.html

But, in both documents, I need to rewrite a lot of things, but I want to keep all the actual behaviors: redirect user on previous page (with referer or on a default page), remember me (in the gurad, I'me forced to return a response on success, else remember me don't work, but I don't really know which response return.... Because if I return null, the redirection work well), messages, etc...

I've search but not found the guard used per default by Symfony to copy/paste it, and just add one rule.

Someone know an other manner, that just consist to rewrite the `checkCredential` ?

Thanks a lot

EDIT (see the answer at the end):
I've found an advanced guard abstract class: `Symfony\Component\Security\Guard\Authenticator\AbstractFormLoginAuthenticator`.Then, the authentication work like in Symfony, now, I just need to add my own test in checkCredentials (in my case in the getUser(), I prefer return the error before retrieve the user.

Comment: You can write a listener for that event.  See here: https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/security/authentication.html#authentication-success-and-failure-events . Write your listener for the `security.authentication.failure` event

Comment: Thanks, but I already have a listener that store the fails, now I want to add a validation check in login, with the stored fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I've found a simply way to do by extending this abstract class: `Symfony\Component\Security\Guard\Authenticator\AbstractFormLoginAuthenticator`. This Authenticator replace the default **FormLoginAuthenticator** used by Symfony, but is very simple, and we just rewrite few methods.

Maybe just found a way to get config.yml value, to define routes (avoid to write it in this file, because we declare it in config).

My service declaration:

```
app.security.form_login_authenticator:
    class: AppBundle\Security\FormLoginAuthenticator
    arguments: ["@router", "@security.password_encoder", "@app.login_brute_force"]
```

My FormLoginAuthenticator:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Security;

use AppBundle\Utils\LoginBruteForce;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Router;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\UserPasswordEncoderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AuthenticationException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\UsernameNotFoundException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserProviderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Guard\Authenticator\AbstractFormLoginAuthenticator;

class FormLoginAuthenticator extends AbstractFormLoginAuthenticator
{
    private $router;
    private $encoder;
    private $loginBruteForce;

    public function __construct(Router $router, UserPasswordEncoderInterface $encoder, LoginBruteForce $loginBruteForce)
    {
        $this->router = $router;
        $this->encoder = $encoder;
        $this->loginBruteForce = $loginBruteForce;
    }

    protected function getLoginUrl()
    {
        return $this->router->generate('login');
    }

    protected function getDefaultSuccessRedirectUrl()
    {
        return $this->router->generate('homepage');
    }

    public function getCredentials(Request $request)
    {
        if ($request->request->has('_username')) {
            return [
                'username' => $request->request->get('_username'),
                'password' => $request->request->get('_password'),
            ];
        }

        return;
    }

    public function getUser($credentials, UserProviderInterface $userProvider)
    {
        $username = $credentials['username'];

        // Check if the asked username is under bruteforce attack, or if client process to a bruteforce attack
        $this->loginBruteForce->isBruteForce($username);

        // Catch the UserNotFound execption, to avoid gie informations about users in database
        try {
            $user = $userProvider->loadUserByUsername($username);
        } catch (UsernameNotFoundException $e) {
            throw new AuthenticationException('Bad credentials.');
        }

        return $user;
    }

    public function checkCredentials($credentials, UserInterface $user)
    {
        // check credentials - e.g. make sure the password is valid
        $passwordValid = $this->encoder->isPasswordValid($user, $credentials['password']);

        if (!$passwordValid) {
            throw new AuthenticationException('Bad credentials.');
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

And, if it's interesting someone, my LoginBruteForce:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Utils;

use Symfony\Component\Cache\Adapter\AdapterInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RequestStack;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Event\AuthenticationFailureEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AuthenticationException;

class LoginBruteForce
{
    // Define constants used to define how many tries we allow per IP and login
    // Here: 20/10 mins (IP); 5/10 mins (username)
    const MAX_IP_ATTEMPTS = 20;
    const MAX_USERNAME_ATTEMPTS = 5;
    const TIME_RANGE = 10; // In minutes

    private $cacheAdapter;
    private $requestStack;

    public function __construct(AdapterInterface $cacheAdapter, RequestStack $requestStack)
    {
        $this->cacheAdapter = $cacheAdapter;
        $this->requestStack = $requestStack;
    }

    private function getFailedLogins()
    {
        $failedLoginsItem = $this->cacheAdapter->getItem('failedLogins');
        $failedLogins = $failedLoginsItem->get();

        // If the failedLogins is not an array, contruct it
        if (!is_array($failedLogins)) {
            $failedLogins = [
                'ip' => [],
                'username' => [],
            ];
        }

        return $failedLogins;
    }

    private function saveFailedLogins($failedLogins)
    {
        $failedLoginsItem = $this->cacheAdapter->getItem('failedLogins');
        $failedLoginsItem->set($failedLogins);
        $this->cacheAdapter->save($failedLoginsItem);
    }

    private function cleanFailedLogins($failedLogins, $save = true)
    {
        $actualTime = new \DateTime('now');
        foreach ($failedLogins as &$failedLoginsCategory) {
            foreach ($failedLoginsCategory as $key => $failedLogin) {
                $lastAttempt = clone $failedLogin['lastAttempt'];
                $lastAttempt = $lastAttempt->modify('+'.self::TIME_RANGE.' minute');

                // If the datetime difference is greatest than 15 mins, delete entry
                if ($lastAttempt <= $actualTime) {
                    unset($failedLoginsCategory[$key]);
                }
            }
        }

        if ($save) {
            $this->saveFailedLogins($failedLogins);
        }

        return $failedLogins;
    }

    public function addFailedLogin(AuthenticationFailureEvent $event)
    {
        $clientIp = $this->requestStack->getMasterRequest()->getClientIp();
        $username = $event->getAuthenticationToken()->getCredentials()['username'];

        $failedLogins = $this->getFailedLogins();

        // Add clientIP
        if (array_key_exists($clientIp, $failedLogins['ip'])) {
            $failedLogins['ip'][$clientIp]['nbAttempts'] += 1;
            $failedLogins['ip'][$clientIp]['lastAttempt'] = new \DateTime('now');
        } else {
            $failedLogins['ip'][$clientIp]['nbAttempts'] = 1;
            $failedLogins['ip'][$clientIp]['lastAttempt'] = new \DateTime('now');
        }

        // Add username
        if (array_key_exists($username, $failedLogins['username'])) {
            $failedLogins['username'][$username]['nbAttempts'] += 1;
            $failedLogins['username'][$username]['lastAttempt'] = new \DateTime('now');
        } else {
            $failedLogins['username'][$username]['nbAttempts'] = 1;
            $failedLogins['username'][$username]['lastAttempt'] = new \DateTime('now');
        }

        $this->saveFailedLogins($failedLogins);
    }

    // This function can be use, when the user reset his password, or when he is successfully logged
    public function resetUsername($username)
    {
        $failedLogins = $this->getFailedLogins();

        if (array_key_exists($username, $failedLogins['username'])) {
            unset($failedLogins['username'][$username]);
            $this->saveFailedLogins($failedLogins);
        }
    }

    public function isBruteForce($username)
    {
        $failedLogins = $this->getFailedLogins();
        $failedLogins = $this->cleanFailedLogins($failedLogins, true);

        $clientIp = $this->requestStack->getMasterRequest()->getClientIp();

        // If the IP is in the list
        if (array_key_exists($clientIp, $failedLogins['ip'])) {
            if ($failedLogins['ip'][$clientIp]['nbAttempts'] >= self::MAX_IP_ATTEMPTS) {
                throw new AuthenticationException('Too many login attempts. Please try again in '.self::TIME_RANGE.' minutes.');
            }
        }
        // If the username is in the list
        if (array_key_exists($username, $failedLogins['username'])) {
            if ($failedLogins['username'][$username]['nbAttempts'] >= self::MAX_USERNAME_ATTEMPTS) {
                throw new AuthenticationException('Maximum number of login attempts exceeded for user: "'.$username.'". Please try again in '.self::TIME_RANGE.' minutes.');
            }
        }

        return;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can listen on the event for failed login attempts.  Create a service:

```
services:
    app.failed_login_listener:
    class: AppBundle\EventListener\AuthenticationFailureListener
    tags:
        - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: security.authentication.failure, method: onAuthenticationFailure }
```

Then create the listener:

```
<?php

namespace App\EventListener;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AuthenticationException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication\AuthenticationFailureHandlerInterface;

class AuthenticationFailureListener implements AuthenticationFailureHandlerInterface
{
    public function onAuthenticationFailure(
        Request $request,
        AuthenticationException $exception
    ) {
        // do whatever
    }
}
```

Modify your service definition to inject whatever other services you may need.

If you want to perform actions after the user logs in, you can do that with the `security.interactive_login` event.  Just throw exceptions if you encounter situations where you want the void the user's login, and perhaps remove their security token or whatever else you need.  You could even do this in your Controller's login action.

For example:

```
services:
    app.security_listener:
    class: AppBundle\EventListener\InteractiveLoginListener
    tags:
        - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: security.interactive_login, method: onInteractiveLogin }
```

Then have your listener:

```
<?php

namespace App\EventListener;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Event\InteractiveLoginEvent;

class InteractiveLoginListener
{
    public function onInteractiveLogin(InteractiveLoginEvent $event)
    {
        // do whatever
    }
}
```

Again inject dependencies as needed.  Also look at Symfony's [creating a custom authentication provider](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/custom_authentication_provider.html) documentation.

Comment: Thanks, but I already have a listener that store the fails, now I want to add a validation check in login, with the stored fails.

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks, I've edited my post too, finally I've found a way to easily do a CustomAuthenticator by implementing `AbstractFormLoginAuthenticator`.

Comment: Glad you found another way, and seems like a good method. I'll check it out and potentially use something like that in the future